# Modify form property within a Public Function

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form called "One" and a module called "Module".

Inside the module I have the following function

```vb
Public Function justTesting()
    MsgBox (Forms!One.innerWidth)
End Function
```

and inside the form "One" I have an "onLoad" event with the following code:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Call justTesting
End Sub
```

I am getting the following error:

> "Run-time error '2450': Microsoft Access cannot find the referenced form 'One".

I have tried several solutions I found on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A form cannot have the name `Form_One` so, my guess is that it is named *One* only.

Thus the code should read:

```vb
Public Function justTesting()
    MsgBox Forms!One.Width
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to make myself as clear as possible and added the "Form_" part as a detailed description. The form name is indeed called "One". However, the error remains the same.

Comment: Don't know about your "innerWidth", but if you change that to a native property like _Width_, it runs.

Comment: Woohoo! Thank you very much. I was finally able to solve the puzzle thanks to your feedback. It is now working properly.

PS: I am not sure why, but while I was using "Forms!One" and after that a dot I was not getting a popup menu listing with all the available commands that can be added. However, once I switched to "Forms(One)" that worked out and from there I was able to see that instead of "innerWidth" the correct property should be "insideWidth".